# How to pass a random parameter to the response in SOAPUI, which would change every n calls

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new in soapui. I make logic for a service stub and I meet a problem.

I have a simple service stub that returns a parameter with a random number (it is randomized in the answer in groovy language), but the problem is that this number is used 2 times per session and cannot be changed, otherwise the session will fail. How would I pass a random number to the next response and then start randomizing again and so on?

I could not find anything similar to my case on the Internet, so I ask the question here. Is it even possible to implement this in soapui, for example through TestSuite and groove scripts?

Groovy code I use in response script to generate random number:
`requestContext.actreq = (10000000 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 9999999));`
Then I substitute `${actreq}` in the response
If the number 100001 is generated, then I would like to pass it to the next two response. In order for Random to work every 2 iterations.

Comment: everything is possible in groovy. how your code looks like?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
I have one response in the method, inside the response I added a groovy script:
requestContext.actreq = (10000000 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 9999999));
and then I replace the static parameter with ${actreq}
I need ${actreq} to return the same value for two calls from the external system. This is a problem, since the requests are not different from each other.

Comment: please edit your question and put code there - there is an ability to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this aproach

```js
class Glob{
   static long callCount=0
   static long randValue=0
   static long rand(){
      callCount ++
      if(callCount % 2 == 1){
        randValue = (10000000 + Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 9999999))
      }
      return randValue
   }
}

requestContext.actreq = Glob.rand()
```

or official way like this:
https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-scripts/

- use setup script to assign `context` variables
- in script you could access those variables like i did in code above to increment call-count and re-calculate random if needed...

Comment: It is working! This is exactly what I need. Apparently, I still have a weak idea in the logic of calls, but there were no problems with how to adjust this code to my code. I will continue to study SOAPUI. I have no words how grateful I am to you!